# After upgrade to 2.4, thingsboard disconnects clients every 10mins

Tags: thingsboard

Upgraded TB from 2.3 to latest version 2.4. Postgress database was updated with included TB script. When using the same clients as per prior version 2.3, the clients disconnect and reconnect every 10 minutes

Deleting and recreating the client 
Updating OS to latest versions and patches (Ubuntu 19.04)
Restarted system
System load is low
Memory usage is 1,2Gb / 3,8Gb

Device and TB server are on same subnet and connected via 100Mbit switch. No disconnects should be experienced

Answer (score 0):

Bug, corrected in version 2.4.1